# Getting error running vs-mda-remote

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova

I followed the instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx 
to install vs-mda-remote. The only thing I noticed was the following:

```
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.7.2: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
```

However the installation completed successfully from what I could tell.
But when I execute vs-mda-remote I get the following error:

```
vs-mda-remote
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
0.2.7

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/lib/cli.js:46
        'lang': process.env.LANG.replace(/_.*/,""), // Convert "en_US.UTF8" to
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/lib/cli.js:46:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/bin/vs-mda-remote:10:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Has anyone encountered this before? The version of NodeJS installed on the Mac is 0.12

Comment: The error points to missing environment variable. So set that in your OS to en_US.UTF-8. Also in the NodeJs CLI, you can type process.env to see all the values in it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

user2458203 got it right, the key is setting the LANG environment variable. If you're unfamiliar with Mac OS (as I am), here's a more detailed version:

- Type this into the terminal: export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
- Verify it by starting the node.js CLI (type "node" into the terminal), and then type "process.env". If you see your new "LANG" variable in the output, you're good to go, vs-mda-remote should work now